# uploading image and creating responsive thumbnail

Tags: responsive-images

I have a simple form and I am using php to upload image to a database where I am only saving the image location (for example; img/example.png").

My problem is how do i create a responsive thumbnail or how do I display the images in a way that doesn't destroy the image quality.

Is there any guide-lines or how to or sort of best practices that you guys can direct me.

Thanks a lot.